# Javascript temporary variable value cleared once I cleared the original value..why?

Tags: javascript

I copied an array to a temporary variable `tempPropertyValuesArray`

And then when I cleared the original array `$scope.advancedSearch.businessCard.propertyValues`

It also cleared the `tempPropertyValuesArray`

I am surprised. Is this the expected behavior ?

Javascript:

```
var tempPropertyValuesArray = $scope.advancedSearch.businessCard.propertyValues;
$log.debug("tempPropertyValuesArray 1 : " +tempPropertyValuesArray);
$scope.advancedSearch.businessCard.propertyValues.length = 0;
$log.debug("tempPropertyValuesArray 2 : " +tempPropertyValuesArray);
```

Logs:

```
tempPropertyValuesArray 1 : [object Object],[object Object] 
tempPropertyValuesArray 2 :
```

Comment: you are currently **referencing** it, not copying, it's different ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In a Javascript I copied an array to a temporary variable tempPropertyValuesArray

You didn't copy it, you made a *reference* to it. Changing the reference, changes the original object.

If you really want a copy, do this:

```
var tempPropertyValuesArray 
      = $scope.advancedSearch.businessCard.propertyValues.slice();
```

Comment: Many thanks how can I copy please

Comment: @Jay - updated answer

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice` would be a whole lot simpler…

Comment: @deceze - pfft, of course it would. I must have had an id10t error.

Comment: But why take the simple route, right?

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks .slice() works.